# SQL Server reporting sub report headers

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

Issue: need header information to repeat on a sub report outside of a table listing.

Creating sub report in SQL Server 2008 Report Builder 3.0. I have a multi-page table sub report. The column headers, on the sub report table, are repeating without issue. I need an over header to go with the table column headers on each page. The main page has account information. Page 2+ contains detail information (sub report) on the account. I need the customer account information (account number, name, address, etc...) to appear at the top of each page of the sub report table listing.

1. Tried putting the table within a List, but the heading only appears on the first page.
2. Added a heading within the table and put the account information there. This worked, but the header is controlled by the column width. I couldn't find a way to modify the column size without effecting all other rows.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're almost there. You just need to try a few things.

1. You can alter the column widths and have them fixed using the **can grow** property on each cell.
2. You have the option to merge a few cells if this helps, then put your information in that as required.
3. Or in your sub report you can add a header to this report and have this header repeated on each page. If you have the customer information in the main page but not the sub report then create a few dummy hidden parameters to pass this information through to the sub report.

Comment: Option 1 worked!!!  I added rows at the top on the table and then merged the cells on the new rows.  This allowed header information to be of different width and height without affecting the table rows.  Header rows repeated on each page.  Thanks.

Comment: Please help other users by accepting this answer. If there's more I can do I'd like to help more.